# AS3 How can I solve the bug of setChildIndex

Tags: actionscript-3

I've gathered all game pages on different frames of movieclip called game. in that game movieclip there are 4 different frames. on third frame I have some drag & drop functionality. When I drag one item, I want it to be on the front, I mean all other objects on that frame must not block the view of current dragging object. I used this.setChildIndex(currentDraggingObject,this.numChildren-1); but the problem is whenever I drag objects, when I change the frame, those objects are shown on that frames as well.

In short description: When I set an object's Index in MovieClip(game) , that object is seen in each frame of MovieClip(game) , how can I fix this?

I've searched the result online but couldn't find a solution.

Thank you

-Ozan

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
this.setChildIndex(currentDraggingObject,this.numChildren-1);
```

You can simply use this:

```
this.addChild(currentDraggingObject); //shorter and clearer
```

If you have some object on a frame and you actually add it again, it indeed stays there in the other frames (I found this out too). The best/fastest solution would be to simple remove them before you are going to change the frame with `this.removeChild(object)`

Comment: But I've not add that objects with addchild in the first place. they are declared on the stage manually. I'm using flash pro cs6. And I don't want to change all those codes just for this problem. I need a solution for my project's current status.

Comment: I understand you didn't add them using addChild. This is the solution for your project's current status.